# Measure of motion in a video

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to get a measure of motion between frames of an American Football match. When the players are set on the line of scrimmage, the motion should be minimal as few parts are moving. Then once the play begins, there will be a sharp increase in motion.

I am aware of optical flow being used to find the general motion between parts of an image. However, is there any way to quantify how much motion is occurring?

Comment: There are ways to quantify motion and they are discussed on [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/opticalflow.html). Converting 3D into 2D is a lossy conversion, so the different algorithms are educated approximations of the lost data.

Comment: Right, those are methods of calculating image flow, which results in vectors of motion. But none of those are values representing how much motion there is between frames.

Answer (score 0):

By taking the sum of all motion vectors, you get global motion between frames.

By definition, the motion vectors calculated by optical flow algorithms will be the transformations between corresponding parts of frame(i) and frame(i+1). Therefore, the amount of motion between two frames is the sum of the motion vectors (motion of each part). You may simply add together their magnitude for a rough estimate of how *chaotic* the transformation/motion was. You may also add together the vectors to receive a new vector that shows net motion.

As far as I can tell, you want the first value; `sum(motionVectors.magnitude)`. This will give you a number allowing you to compare (roughly), the amount of motion in two different frames. This also allows you to graph motion over time, allowing you to compare two videos using metrics such as 'unexpected motion', or 'total motion'.

There are many uses for this data, and I'll leave them to your imagination.